# How to use alternation with lookbehind

Tags: r, regex

***Aim:***

I would like to match sentences with the word 'no' but only if 'no' is not preceeded by 'with' or 'there is' or 'there are' in r.

***Input:***

```
The ground was rocky with no cracks in it
No diggedy, no doubt
Understandably, there is no way an elephant can be green
```

***Expected output:***

```
The ground was rocky with no cracks in it
Understandably, there is no way an elephant can be green
```

***Attempt:***

```
gsub(".*(?:((?<!with )|(?<!there is )|(?<!there are ))\\bno\\b(?![?:A-Za-z])|([?:]\\s*N?![A-Za-z])).*\\R*", "", input_string, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

***Problem:***

The negative lookbehind seems to be ignored so that all the sentences are replaced. Is the problem the use of alternation in a the lookbehind statement?

Comment: How do you define *sentence* (separated by `.` or newline or something else)?

Comment: @PoGibas. It is defined by newline.

Comment: Sebastian, are you sure you need `([?:]\\s*N?![A-Za-z])` and not `[?:]\\s*N(?![A-Za-z])` in your pattern? Like `N` not followed with a letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?mxi)^       # Start of a line (and free-spacing/case insensitive modes are on)
(?:           # Outer container group start
  (?!.*\b(?:with|there\h(?:is|are))\h+no\b) # no 'with/there is/are no' before 'no'
  .*\bno\b  # 'no' whole word after 0+ chars
  (?![?:])    # cannot be followed with ? or :
|             # or
  .*          # any 0+ chars
  [?:]\h*n(?![a-z]) # ? or : followed with 0+ spaces, 'n' not followed with any letter
)             # container group end
.*            # the rest of the line and 
\R*           # 0+ line breaks
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHER2d/2). In short: the pattern finds 2 alternatives, either of the 2 types of lines, one with `no` whole word in it that is not preceded with `with`, `there is` or `there are` and a space after them, or a line that contains `?` or `:` followed with 0+ horizontal spaces (`\h`) and then an `n` not followed with any other letter.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/erY9jb):

```
sentences <- "The ground was rocky with no cracks in it\r\nNo diggedy, no doubt\r\nUnderstandably, there is no way an elephant can be green"
rx <- "(?mxi)^ # Start of a line
(?:            # Outer container group start
  (?!.*\\b(?:with|there\\h(?:is|are))\\h+no\\b) # no 'with/there is/are no' before 'no'
  .*\\bno\\b   # 'no' whole word after 0+ chars
  (?![?:])     # cannot be followed with ? or :
|              # or
  .*           # any 0+ chars
  [?:]\\h*n(?![a-z]) # ? or : followed with 0+ spaces, 'n' not followed with any letter
)              # container group end
.*             # the rest of the line and 0+ line breaks
\\R*"
res <- gsub(rx, "", sentences, perl=TRUE)
cat(res, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
The ground was rocky with no cracks in it
Understandably, there is no way an elephant can be green
```

Thanks to the `x` modifier, you may add comments to the regex pattern and use spaces to format it for better readability. Note that all literal whitespace must be replaced with `\\h` (horizontal whitespace), `\\s` (any whitespace), `\\n` (LF), `\\r` (CR), etc. to make it work in such a pattern.

The `(?i)` modifier stands for the `ingore.case=TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to have a regex alternation character. Idea is to match and capture all the possible "no" sentences and match all the remaining sentences. Then replace all the matched characters with `\\1` ie, characters from the first capturing group.

```
gsub("(?i)(.*(with|there (?:is|are)) no\\b.*)|.*", "\\1" ,string, perl=T)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/BE9Fi5/3)

Example:

```
x <- "The ground was rocky with no cracks in it\nNo diggedy, no doubt\nUnderstandably, there is no way an elephant can be green"
gsub("(?i)(.*(with|there (?:is|are)) no\\b.*\\n?)|.*\\n?", "\\1" ,x, perl=T)
# [1] "The ground was rocky with no cracks in it\nUnderstandably, there is no way an elephant can be green"
```